# Python: Load numpy arrays (npys) with specific columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, load

I have saved arrays as npy with sizes around 2GB. Can I somehow load only specific columns,rows with numpy.load ? I did not find a command for that or is there a workaround for that case?

Comment: There is the possibility of a memmap'd npy file.  See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620395/1005575

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `.npy` files. For that kind of problems, it is better recommended to use `.h5` files, with the `h5py` package. You will find an example in this post: [h5py: how to read selected rows of an hdf5 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419453/h5py-how-to-read-selected-rows-of-an-hdf5-file).