# Read a single column from a HDF5 dataframe in C

Tags: c, hdf5

I have a HDF5 database and I need to load iteratively just one row per time. I'm having trouble understanding how to use the `H5Sselect_hyperslab`.

There is a similar topic related to the h5py library in Python ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419453/h5py-how-to-read-selected-rows-of-an-hdf5-file](https://stackoverflow.com)), but I can't find the corresponding thread in C.

Comment: Not sure why the upvote here.  Can you at least show your attempt at coding, including the call(s) you make using the API.   Gaining understanding sometimes requires a little _doing_, even if your attempts are not successful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are not enough details here to even define a problem, let alone how to approach solving the problem.   OP should provide attempt at coding, with specific information on where exactly the problem occurred, i.e. what was the expectation, where did results differ.